# Fisher matrix with penalty function

Tags: correlation, maximum-likelihood, fisher-information

I am fitting a parametric model to human tracking data. Because my data is in part corrupted (see below why), as such I had to introduce a penalty function to my optimization algorithm.

The Fisher matrix is the inverse of the Hessian, but how does a non-continuous penalty function influence the Fisher matrix? I could not get a grip on it during derivation.

**Background information**

Ideally, I'd run maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE) where the residual can be assumed to be normally distributed. Computing the Fisher information matrix is here computed as the inverse of the Hessian, or simplified to (my *matlab* code):

```
% calculate output error
Res = y_measured - y_simulated;

% estimate of the residual covariance (measurement noise covariance)
R = 1/length(Res)*Res.'*Res;


% Estimate Fisher information matrix F
F = -dydp.'*inv(R)*-dydp;
```

Where dydp is the first order derivative of my model with respect to it's parameters.

Now I have to optimize the likelihood with penalty

```
L = L + N*1e3
```

Where L is the likelihood and N the amount of oscillations induced by a model (see below) There is no (continuous analytical) derivative for this with respect to the parameters. How does the penalty function affect the computation of the Fisher Information Matrix?

---

I did a tracking experiment on a touchscreen. Touchscreens have a software controlled input lag. This input lag is very dominant for discrete point-to-point targets, as you will 'lose' some data. For one, humans do not have discrete velocity jumps, where the output-data of the touchscreen has discrete jumps caused by the input delay. A penalty function to weigh osclitations induced by this artifact 'solves' the problem.